# Debug Setting in .Net 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

With the debug setting gone in the web.config, what setting turns on and off debug and what is the equivalent (if any) for the following in .Net 5 (MVC 6 project)?

```
#define DEBUG
// ...
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

Comment: The web.config does not contain #DEBUG. #DEBUG is a compiler directive, not a web.config setting. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: @Igor - There is no web config in vNext projects

Comment: I stand corrected, it is possible to define in the 4.5 version of .NET in the web.config in section compiler attribute compilerOptions.

Comment: Thanks Igor but I'm talking about .Net 5 which uses Project.json files.

Comment: @RickJames - I understood, I was commenting that my previous comment was not right :). Can you post a link to the source about this? The only thing I was able to find is that they are removing it from the web.config but maybe you can still put it in your code directly like you did up in your example and pass the directive in to your compiler at compile time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Since writing this answer I have learned that the new way in .Net Core is to use Environment Variables.  You can find an article [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html) and more info [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Environment-Variables).

You can set the environment variable in your project properties under debug. The code would look like after using DI to inject `IHostingEnvironment`

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    //...
}
```

**END UPDATE**

The answer by [@user2095880](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28464572/debug-setting-in-net-5/28464815#28464815) is valid and does work.  However, you may want a solution that you do not need to change the project.json to go to production.

```
#if DEBUG
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello DEBUG CODE!");
            });
#else
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello LIVE CODE!");
            });
#endif
```

This checks your solution configuration (still works in .Net 5) if you are in Debug or something else.  If your solution configuration is set to Debug, the first set of code will run.  If you select Release (or anything else), the second code section will run.  See the image below for the dropdown to change from Debug to Release.

[image]

Comment: The difference here is that the pre-processor directives are determining the target environment at compile-time. The solution involving the `IHostingEnvironment` determines the environment at run-time. They are both valid approaches, but for different problems.

Answer (score 7):

In your project json file, you need to add:

```
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
        "compilationOptions": {
            "define": [ "WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_CALL_IT" ]
        }
    },
    "aspnetcore50": {
        "compilationOptions": {
            "define": [ "WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_CALL_IT" ]
        }
    }
```

then in your code you use it as follows:

```
#if WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_CALL_IT
    .. your code..
#endif
```

where WHATEVER_YOU_WANT_TO_CALL_IT can = DEBUG or whatever else.

Comment: Does it possible to have for single framework two different configuration?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I don't see why not, but I have not tested it yet.

Comment: Seems that this is deprecated and now we should use "buildOptions" according to a compiler warning reported